# Is there any way to recreate packages.config file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I accidentally missed to upload to source control NuGet packages.config file and it got deleted somehow :(

Is there any way to recreate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kind of tricky to do it in an automated way.  Easiest is to simply re-create the `packages.config` manually, added entries for each directory in the `packages` dir.  For example, I have the following dirs in my packages directory:

```
Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.3
Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.16
Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.15
Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.8
repositories.config
WindowsAzure.MobileServices.1.0.2
WPtoolkit.4.2013.08.16
```

If I were to re-create the packages.config, I could simply take the directory name, separate the version number and create a line for each package like:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="wp71" />
```

adding the `targetFramework` attribute to whatever target that project was using.

Then wrap all of those `<package>` elements with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
 <!--...-->
</packages>
```

Resulting in something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.16" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.15" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.MobileServices" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="wp71" />
  <package id="WPtoolkit" version="4.2013.08.16" targetFramework="wp71" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Looks like they may be moving to a json format: https://docs.nuget.org/Consume/ProjectJson-Format

Answer (score 7):

An easier way will be just go to Nuget and reinstall the packages. It will create the package.config file

Comment: Doing so will upgrade to the newest version of the packages though which may not be desirable.

Comment: So new to nuget myself.  nuget install packagename doesn't seem to generate a configuration file..  Just seems to download the packages into the local directory.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the console-manager?

For restoring you van both use the NuGet package manager as the console.

[Restore packages using Package Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore)

Some things only work with the console ??(?correct?)

[Micrsoft Docs: How to reinstall and update packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages#when-to-reinstall-a-package)

Ref.: [Why, when and how to reinstall NuGet packages after upgrading a project](https://mderriey.com/2018/07/18/why-when-and-how-to-reinstall-nuget-packages/)